# deep zoom is not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, deepzoom

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + Windows Vista Enterprise x86. I have used Silverlight Deep Zoom composer tool to export my composed images into Siverlight type. Everything is previewed fine after export successful message (I select browse from browser).

But when I click the Test.html in the exported project to show Deep Zoom effects from browser, nothing is displayed. Here is my screen snapshot. Any ideas what is wrong?

http://i41.tinypic.com/2dac561.jpg

EDIT 1:

to my surprise, there is no clientbin folder in my exported project.

I have made two screen snapshots for,

1. my project folder generated by Deep Zoom Composer under Exported Data folder;
2. the content of GeneratedImages folder under my project folder.

Please refers them to,

http://i42.tinypic.com/346ncec.jpg

http://i42.tinypic.com/15zqkn9.jpg

Any ideas what is wrong?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

When you created your silverlight project, did you host the silverlight application in a new Web site? If not, try it.