# Silverlight Image element not showing up

Tags: silverlight, image, silverlight-3.0

Silverlight newbie question:

I've got a small Silverlight application with the following XAML snippet:

```
<Image Source="http://judahhimango.com/images/smileys/cool.gif" />
```

The image doesn't show up! I would expect the image to download asynchronously, then show up in the UI, but alas, no such luck.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update** -------------------------------------------------

Ok, no-go on the .GIFs, forgot about that. But using a PNG doens't work either:

```
<Image Source="http://judahhimango.com/images/smileys/cool.png" />
```

However, if I change the Source to a BitmapImage, then it works:

```
<Image>
      <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="http://judahhimango.com/images/smileys/cool.png" />
      </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Why can't I just specify the Image Source? Why do I have to specify a BitmapImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SL does not support gifs:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/3883/232781.aspx
can you try a jpg?

3/9/10: Editing per request:
I can't post complete code, but here is my MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Image Source="http://judahhimango.com/images/smileys/cool.png"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

3/9/10: OK, I think I know what your problem may be. When you create a new silverlight application project in Visual Studio, it gives you the option of hosting it in an ASP.NET website. **Did you select that option? If not, please select it, and give it a try**. See this:
[deep zoom is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053081/deep-zoom-is-not-displayed/2413697#2413697)

Comment: Ah, that would explain it, wouldn't it? :-) Thanks, I'll give a jpg a try.

Comment: PNG still doesn't work. If I change the Image's Source property to a BitmapSource, then it works. I'm updating the question, perhaps you can update your answer?

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look; if it works out, I'll gladly mark yours as the answer and vote you up.

Comment: Looks like the comment mangled that. Can you edit your post instead with that? Then I'll give it a try.

Comment: I am not able to edit previous comment. I am not having any problem with <Image Source="judahhimango.com/images/smileys/cool.png"/> inserted in a Grid.

Comment: Really? That's bizarre, I am having that problem. Which Silverlight version are you using?

Comment: @Morpheus: please don't post significant code in comments it just doesn't format well,  edit your answer to include the code there.

Comment: using 3.0. although i did not try, i expect 2.0 should also work. i deleted my old comment, which did not format well.

Comment: morpheus, for the sake of the internet audience, would you mind editing your post to include the code sample?

Comment: Now that I've upgraded to SL 4, I never have these problems. I think this was a rare, intermittent bug in SL 3 that has now been fixed in SL 4.

Answer (score 2):

I changed two properties on my png image:  `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output` Direct `Copy always`.